# Why `pow(sum,1/2)` is not giving me the same result as `sqrt(sum))`?

Tags: c, square-root

In the code at the end, there is a function at the bottom called `general_norm` that uses the following `print()` functions:

```
printf(" %f",sqrt(sum));
printf(" %f",pow(sum,1/2));
```

While `sqrt(sum))` is giving me the correct result, I don't understand why `pow(sum,1/2)` is not considering that `√x = x½`.

Could you help me figure out what I am missing? Thank you! :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


void print_vector(int N,float * V);
void save_vector(int N,float * V);
void absolute_values(int N,float * V, float * VABS);
void maximum_value(int N, float * VABS);
void general_norm(int N, float * VABS);


int main(void)
{

    const int n=4;
    int i;
    float v[n],vabs[n];

    puts("Enter the 5 components of the vector:");
    save_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe vector is:");
    print_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe absolute vector is:");
    absolute_values(n, v, vabs);

    puts("\nThe maximum value is:");
    maximum_value(n, vabs);

    puts("\nThe general norm is:");
    general_norm(n, vabs);

    return 0;
}

void save_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        scanf("%f",V+i);
}

void print_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf(" %.2f ",*(V+i));
}

void absolute_values(int N, float *V, float *VABS)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        VABS[i]=((V[i]<0)?-V[i]:V[i]);
        printf(" %f", VABS[i]);
    }
}

void maximum_value(int N, float * VABS)
{
  int i;
  float maximum;
  maximum = VABS[0];

  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
  {
    if (VABS[i] > maximum)
    {
       maximum = VABS[i];
    }
  }
  printf(" %f", maximum);
}

void general_norm(int N, float * VABS)
{
  int i;
  float sum;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
    sum=sum+pow(VABS[i],2);
    }
  printf(" %f",sqrt(sum));
  printf(" %f",pow(sum,1/2));
}
```

Comment: Integer math.  `1/2` is 0.  Either use `0.5`, or force the type `1.0 / 2.0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @1201ProgramAlarm. I just added your answer as the final one below. Thank you again for your very quick help!! :-)

Comment: You should not expect `sqrt(x)` to be exactly equal to `pow(x, 0.5)` either; pow usually uses a different algorithm that can't, in general, be quite as accurate.  (If it is exactly equal on your computer, that probably means the pow implementation notices a second argument of 0.5 and calls sqrt.)

Comment: Aside: `printf("Enter the %d components of the vector:\n", n);` make more sense than `puts("Enter the 5 components of the vector:");`

Comment: Tip: for greater insight to the potential differences of `sqrt(sum), pow(sum,0.5)`, use exponential notation: `printf(" %e",sqrt(sum) - pow(sum,0.5));`

Comment: `general_norm()` fails as `sum` is not initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leaving here the answer 1201ProgramAlarm gave me:

Integer math. `1/2` is `0`. Either use `0.5`, or force the type `1.0 / 2.0`.

`1.0 / 2` would also work.